# caw.vimによるコメントアウト

Tags: vim

caw.vimを使っているのですが、Ctrl+kでコメントアウトすると

```
/*hoge*/
/*fuga*/
```

のようにそれぞれの行でコメントアウトになってしまいます。

```
/*hoge
fuga*/
```

とか

```
/*
hoge
fuga
*/
```

のようにならないかなと思っているのですが、そういうコマンドはないのでしょうか。
別のプラグインでも構いません。

どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/tyru/caw.vim のREADMEを読むと以下の通りボックスコメントもサポートしているようです。(デフォルトのキーマップが`gcw`または`gcb`)

```
Type "gcw" (uncomment: "gcuw")
  before:
      "  wrap!"
  after:
      "  /* wrap! */"

Type "gcb"
  before:
      "  box!"
  after:
      "  /********/"
      "  /* box! */"
      "  /********/"
```